# R/W Permission Kubernetes over NFS

Tags: permissions, nfs, kubernetes

I have kubernetes pod with a PHP  & Nginx containers , mounting an NFS share v4.1, as /var/www/html/"webcontent"
When I access the application from browser throws the error "You need to grant write permissions for PHP on the following directory: /var/www/html"
The NFS server is a Sinology NAS, no mapping enabled, so it should default to use UID=33 GID=33 . Both are synced in the NFS server and everywhere on the cluster
If i try to get in the container with kubectl exec -it nginx-phpfpm /bin/bash , I can see both the owner and and groups, as www-data, all permissions result granted as in :
[Inside Container as root : Permission and ownership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5v9b.png)

[Inside Conainer as root : Folder Permission and ownership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzMft.png)

All permissions looks granted, but still i am unable to run the application :
[Prestashop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNp75.png)

Now, all is left looks pointing to the way the container mounts the NFS share,
The application (Prestashop) can't be at fault since i tried, works with block storage.

May this have to do with the Pod's security context ? [PV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5pa.png)
[PVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTdik.png)

Any additional information will be provided,

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the problem could be related to fsgroup permission.

(1) Check the readOnly settings in Volume mount

(2) Check the securityContexts (fsgroup), Does the PHP user belong to the same UID(33) and Group ID(33)